# Is there any difference in using &:first-of-type vs only the :first-of-type in scss

Tags: sass

Is there any difference in using `&:first-of-type` nested within apple class vs only `:first-of-type` nested within all-fruits class. Because they both give same results by making the apple word in color red. How to know when to use them?

html:

```
<div class="all-fruits">
    <p class="fruit apple">Apple</p>
    <p class="fruit strawberries">Strawberries</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
$apple: red;



.all-fruits{ 
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  .apple {
    color: $apple;
  }
  :first-of-type {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
}
```

vs

```
.all-fruits{
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  .apple {
    color: $apple;
     &:first-of-type {
       font-size: 100px;
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference in using `&:first-of-type` ... vs only `:first-of-type`

Yes, there is a difference between those two and it can be a very big difference in some cases. Have a look at the CSS generated from your SASS examples:

```css
/* :first-of-type example */

.all-fruits :first-of-type {
  font-size: 100px;
}

/* &:first-of-type example */

.all-fruits .apple:first-of-type {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

In first example you are saying "set font-size to 100px to any element that descends from .all-fruits element, assuming it is the first element of its type". So if you ever add any non-paragraph element to your `.all-fruits` div, it will also have a font-size of 100px. Consider following example:

```html
<div class="all-fruits">
  <p class="fruit apple">Apple</p>
  <p class="fruit strawberries">Strawberries</p>
  <span>Yummy!</span>
</div>
```

With `.all-fruits :first-of-type` the span will also have 100px font-size, while `.all-fruits .apple:first-of-type` would ensure only those elements that are first of their type AND have `.apple` class get 100px fonts.

> Because they both give same results ... How to know when to use them?

Both giving the same result in some specific case is no excuse for assuming both are equally good for the job. I believe following CSS would give you the same result with your current HTML:

```css
.all-fruits {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.all-fruits .apple {
  color: red;
}
*:not(:last-of-type) {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

But it does not mean that my `:not` selector is any good at all. In fact, it would be a terrible decision to use that selector.

While it's hard to predict all possible additions to current HTML and write a 100% future-proof CSS, more often than not, it's a good idea to apply styles via classes instead of very generic or universal selectors.

In your case, `.apple:first-of-type` seems to be a better choice than just `:first-of-type`. If I assume a little more about your requirements, I would also consider using `.fruit:first-of-type` as it would increase font-size of any fruit that is first in the list, not just apples.